# vim - Append next line to end of current

Tags: vim

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I haven't had much luck with a search. Is there an easy way to append the next line to the end of the current line?

Example:

```
this.thing = that
    .getThing();
```

I am looking for a one-stroke command that turns it into:

```
this.thing = that.getThing();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> joins the next line with the current one. It removes indentation but usually adds a space, unfortunately.

> These commands, except "gJ", insert one space in place of the `<EOL>` unless
>   there is trailing white space or the next line starts with a ')'.  These
>   commands, except "gJ", delete any leading white space on the next line.

Comment: Hey, it's better than going to the start of the next line then deleting backwards! :)

Comment: `Jx` will join and remove the joining space.

Answer (score 5):

Use `J` which is short for [join](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#J).

Vim doc copied below

```
                            *J*
J           Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines.
            Remove the indent and insert up to two spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the other answers, if you want to keep the cursor position you can use a mark:

```
:nnoremap J mzJ`z
```

- `mz` - add mark to register `z`
- `J` - join as usual
- `` `z `` - go to the mark set